# Calculate form size to automatically adopt to screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I don't know what keyword do I need to use to search for this but..

Since the form has its `WindowState` property, to make it automatically maximized to any resolution, I want it like, *maximize to* 60-80% only.
How do you do this?

```
Me.Size = MaximumSize - 20%
```

Is there something like that?

Comment: Width and Height of form can be set for this purpose

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Resolution Of Form Based On Screen Resolution ( without changing monitor resolution and using Maximized screen option )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643693/change-resolution-of-form-based-on-screen-resolution-without-changing-monitor)

Comment: Just use the tips the guy gave as answer in link I posted above.
And then set CurrentScreenWidth and CurrentScreenHeight (minus) what you want

Comment: Give me a minute. sorry, its kinda hard to know what proper words must be use in google :)

Comment: @Nidzaaaa didn't find the answer there, though I have updated my question.

Comment: Check out the Screen class.

Comment: @AdorableVB you can use that CurrentScreenWidth and CurrentScreenHeight then * (times) (20/100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim PercentScreenWidth As Integer = 20
Dim PercentScreenHeight As Integer = 20
Dim CurrentScreenWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Dim CurrentScreenHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
Dim RatioX as Double = CurrentScreenWidth * (PercentScreenWidth / 100) 
Dim RatioY as Double = CurrentScreenHeight * (PercentScreenHeight / 100)
MyForm.Width = RatioX 
MyForm.Height = RatioY
```

This should work fine and solve all your problems.
This code should be used in `Form.Load`

After some testing I figured out that you have to put MyForm.ShowDialog() so that form actualy resize acording to your setups. But this could work in this way only if you call that form from another form, since I couldn't find a solution for StartUp Form to be resized in this way (wierd, but true).

Comment: computation could work with just `- 20%`.. Although it does not work for me. Its just offsetting to the bottom right by 80%..